# Translation check from C++ to ObjectPascal which is better

Tags: c++, pointers, translate, delphi

I am translating some C++ code to ObjectPascal (first time), and C++ is still fairly new to me.

The C++ header file looks like this:

```
class RenumFd {
public:
    RenumFd(int length);
    ~RenumFd();
    void CompFd(double *buff);

//...other public functions cut for space

private:
    void rmfd(int n, int isgn, double *a, int *ap, double *kw);

//...other private functions cut for space

    int _length;
    int *_ap;
    double *_kw;
}
```

I have translated them this way:

```
Type
 TRenumFD = class
 private
   _length: integer;
   _ap: Pinteger;
   _kw: Pdouble;
   procedure rmfd(n:integer; isgn:integer; var a:double; var ap:integer; var kw:double);

//... other procedures cut for space   

public
  constructor Create(const length:integer);
  destructor  Destroy(); override;
  procedure CompFd(var buff:double);
end;
```

I read that pointers used as parameters in C++ should be set as var parameters in Object Pascal. Is that correct, or should I stick to a more literal translation (worried about being bitten later).

Also in the C++ constructor there is the following code, which I am unsure about in one line.

```
RenumFd::RenumFd(int length) {
    _length = length;
    _ap = new int[2 + (1 << ((int)(log(2.0 + length) + 0.5) / 2))];
    _ap[0] = 0;  <-- is this setting the pointer to nil, or assigning 0?

    //...

}
```

I am unsure if I should translate that line in Object Pascal to filling the first element with zero or assigning to nil:

```
_ap := AllocMem(2 + (1 shl (trunc(ln(2.0 + length) + 0.5) / 2))) * sizeOf(integer));
_ap := nil;
```

Maybe I am trying too hard to guess the intent?

Comment: You should be concerned about destructors and exceptions (the rest is trivial compared to that) !

Comment: Also, you should be using `Ln` for natural logarithm in Pascal.

Comment: Almost impossible to give sound advice given that you've removed all the interesting and relevant code. Type declarations give little away. Usage would show intent and semantics. The C++ code looks a little lame anyway with all those raw pointers. Is this code from the 80s? I would not translate it. I'd write fresh code using the correct idiom for the language I was writing in.

Comment: My bad. I was worried about putting too much code up (can you believe that?). But to your point. I think this was originally C translated to C++. It is engineering code for some DSP work. I would prefer to remove older style writing and have it more OP like. It needs to be translated to be more flexible with all the OP code we use, but beyond making it functional, it would be nice if we could understand each part. That is what I am having trouble with. I think more in OP than C or C++. Before I ask more questions I am going to try using Dyn arrays. I understand that.

Comment: @Michelle, you dont need a dynamic array there, in the fact. Look at the expression which results in the number of elements `new` is going to allocate. It is a constant. Regular array is applicable if you are willing to sacrifice that nice expression (coz Borland compilers hate reals in constant expressions)

Comment: @free Consulting, So the error revealing continues. Yes, I do need a dyn array. I forgot to include the length param in the formula. Added Ln for pascal too. Who's Borland?

Comment: @free which expression is constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decision to use a `var` or a pointer really depends on how it is going to be used, and whether it can be set to `nil` or not.  Typically `var` is better, but pointer has its uses.  You did not provide enough code to show which decision is best.

As for the array allocation, a **dynamic array** would be a better choice than `AllocMem()`:

```
type
  RenumFd = class
  public
    constructor Create(length: Integer);
    //...    
  private
    _ap: array of Integer;
    //...
  end;
```

```
constructor RenumFd.Create(length: Integer);
begin
  SetLength(_ap, 2 + (1 shl (Trunc(log(2.0) + 0.5) div 2)));
  _ap[0] := 0; // <-- assigns 0 to the first integer in the array
  //...
end;
```

Comment: Ok, point taken. I definitely did not provide enough code. However, now, looking over the rest of the code, I actually think if I just declare the variables as normal arrays (that was the key-seeing them as arrays) and pass them by var, it will work out fine. I got caught up in trying to keep everything as pointers.

Answer (score 1):

In general, your translation is of good quality.

> I read that pointers used as parameters in C++ should be set as var
>   parameters in Object Pascal. Is that correct, or should I stick to a
>   more literal translation (worried about being bitten later).

I'd say it is partially correct. Using typed pointer as parameter is lower-level way to implement [passing parameters by reference](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Parameters_%28Delphi%29#Value_and_Variable_Parameters). It adds a flexibility to pass NULL pointer (`nil`) instead of real variable reference, effectively making parameter optional. You should examine your code for such checks (`if (kw) { *kw = ...; } /* writes to kw only if requested */`). If there is no intent to make pointer parameter(s) optional, then you should stick to higher-level *by reference* declarations (`var` or `out`).

> ```
> _ap[0] = 0;  <-- is this setting the pointer to nil, or assigning 0?
> ```
>
> I am unsure if I should translate that line in Object Pascal to
>   filling the first element with zero or assigning to nil:
>
> ```
> _ap := AllocMem(2 + (1 shl (trunc(log(2.0) + 0.5) / 2))) * sizeOf(integer));
> _ap := nil;
> ```
>
> Maybe I am trying too hard to guess the intent?

You clearly got implicit dereferencing in the questionable line, so it writes 0 to the very first element of `_ap`. It is illogical to overwrite pointer to the recent memory allocation, isn't it? Your literal Pascal translation should be: `_ap^ := 0;`

But note what `new` operator allocates more than 1 `int`, so your `PInteger` type is not enough, you need `PIntegerArray`. That is:

```
type TIntegerArray = array[0..MaxInt div SizeOf(Integer)] of Integer;
type PIntegerArray = ^TIntegerArray;
```

Declaring `_ap` to this type will save you a lot of typecasting and still remains as close to the C++ original as possible. I do not agree what you need a dynamic array is absolute good choice here.

One last word (minor):

```
constructor Create(const length:integer);
```

I see no purpose of passing this integer by constant reference and it does not match original C++ code literally. There will be no effect at all, but I'd remove `const`.

Comment: Thank you. These are very good points, and it is somewhat embarrassing to see it so clearly now. I need to get better at deciphering the actual memory usage. For the record, my first _ap := ? attempt was _ap^ := 0, but then ap^[0] :=, and then... the horrors! Again thanks!